# Does the Middle East Institute partner with Northrop Grumman, Raytheon, Chevron, ExxonMobil and Saudi Aramco?

Tags: military, media

[This](http://www.newsbud.com/2016/10/27/washington-war-party-urges-obama-to-go-to-war-against-assad-the-russians/) newsbud article claims:

> Lister was formerly a visiting fellow at the Brookings Doha Center in
>   Qatar and is now a senior fellow at the Washington, D.C.-based
>   **Middle East Institute**, which describes itself as “an unbiased source of information and analysis” on the Middle East and **partners
>   with corporations such as Northrop Grumman, Raytheon, Chevron,
>   ExxonMobil and Saudi Aramco.**

The same story was reblogged in [this](https://actualitserlande.wordpress.com/2016/10/28/scott-net-29102016/) site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can see the [MEI's 2013 annual report](http://www.mei.edu/sites/default/files/MEI_AnnualReport2013_final.pdf) with page 10 showing its Grantors and Sponsors, including the names you list and many more such as the US Department of State, Microsoft and the Coca-Cola Company.

[image]